# Multiple login methods for an account

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

We're working on an MVC5 system which will have a website and a web API. Authentication method will be asp.net Identity using Individual accounts/local login.

The website requires the standard user/password log in.

The Web API will be used via a handheld device (Windows CE devices with integrated barcode scanner) and the user story defines that a PIN (4-6 digit number) would be preferable to a complex password on that device.

The same userId will have a complex password for logging into the website and ideally a PIN for logging into the handheld.

I've created a relatively simple solution of creating 2 accounts when a user is registered.

A normal user account with a username of "MART0001" which will only be accepted on website.

Asecondary account with characters appended to the end of the username "MART0001_^".  The secondary account can have a PIN password and will only be accepted when called from web API.

It's not ideal as I have to relax the ApplicationUserManager PasswordValidator rules to allow a PIN to be accepted and manage my own complex characters password validation rules for entry of the primary account password.

I've also got to manage users forgetting their password/PIN by allowing reset of either/both accounts.

Can anyone think of a more elegant solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. Having two user accounts for one user is untenable. Keeping the accounts in sync is going to be a nightmare, if you can manage it at all. Add the pin as a separate column, and do custom authentication when pin is provided. Basically, you just select the user using something like `UserManager.FindByEmailAsync`, instead of `UserManager.PasswordSignInAsync`. Then, you manually check whether or not the pin matches. If it does, sign the user in with `SignInManager.SignInAsync`. If not, you return the typical sign in failure error message.

You should of course hash the pin in the database and compare it to a hash of the pin the user enters, the same as passwords are handled. You should be able to make use of `UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword` and `UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword` to hash the pin stored in the database and verify the pin the user enters, respectively.

**When pin is being set**

```
user.Pin = UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(pin);
```

**When logging in with pin**

```
var user = UserManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
if (user != null && UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user.Pin, pin))
{
    await SignInManager.SigInAsync(user, isPersistent, rememberBrowser);
    // redirect
}

// return error
```